# How should I repair this hole in my tile grout?

Tags: tile, grout

I have a section on a grout line where there's a white/grey dot. Is this a hole? How do I touch it up? Can I just apply grout sealer?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The white/grey not a hole, but the black dot might be.  Can you push a small nail/pin into it?  Where is the grout line, a very wet area like a shower floor or someplace else?

Comment: I revised your title. You don't need _us_ to tell you whether that's a hole or not. No one is better suited to that job than you. :)

Answer (score 1):

That looks like two things to me (neither of which are of concern): A bit of off-color mixture and a tiny air pocket.

Grout sealer doesn't repair grout. It's a very low-viscosity fluid designed to penetrate the grout and make it watertight. It doesn't leave much of a coating, and it doesn't fill voids. Usually. A heavy application, or several, may fill this. It probably won't mask it very well, though.

If that comically small flaw bothers you, get some matching grout and do a repair. Either just rub some over that area, or scrape out a channel and refill.